# TSA007 suitcase reset button stuck

Tags: luggage, tsa

I have a Herschel suitcase and the reset button is pressed in and now stuck, which means any combination will unlock the suitcase. does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Is your suitcase still under warranty? If not, call a suitcase repair shop (they exist!) and ask for an estimate.